# Error importing CSV/Excel files to Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to import .xlsx and .csv files in my Rails application but it gave me this error:

```
NoMethodError at /admin/member_imports
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried creating new member and student from the Rails console and it was successful. But I cannot figure out why I am not able to import the spreadsheets.

The following code is in my app/models/member_import.rb file

```
class MemberImport
  include ActiveModel::Model
  require 'roo'

  attr_accessor :file
  attr_accessor :club_id

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each { |student_reg, value| send("#{student_reg}=", value) }
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def open_spreadsheet
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end

  def load_imported_products
    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)

    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      member = Member.find_by(student_reg: row["student_reg"], club_id: club_id) || Member.new
      
      begin 
        @getstudent = Student.find_by(student_reg: row["student_reg"].upcase)
        member.student_id = @getstudent.id
      rescue
        member.student_id = nil
      end

      member.club_id = club_id
      begin 
        member.attributes = row.to_hash
      rescue
        return false
      end
      member.attributes = row.to_hash
      member
    end    
  end

  def imported_products
    @imported_products ||= load_imported_products
  end

  def save
    if imported_products == false
      return false
    end
    begin 
        imported_products.map(&:valid?).all?
          imported_products.each(&:save!)
          true
      rescue
        imported_products.each_with_index do |member, index|
          if member.valid?
            member.save
            errors.add :base, "<span>Row #{index+2}: #{member.student_reg} : Student Added Successfully</span>".html_safe
          end

          member.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            errors.add :base, "<strong>ERROR - Row #{index+2}: #{member.student_reg} : Student Registration not found - ERROR</strong>".html_safe
          end
        end
        false
    end
  end


end
```

The following code is my app/controller/admin/member_imports_controller.rb file

```
class Admin::MemberImportsController < AdminController

  def index
    @member_import = MemberImport.new
    @club = Club.all.order(:name)
  end

  def create
    @member_import = MemberImport.new(params[:member_imports])
    if @member_import.save
      flash[:success] = "Import Members successfully."
      redirect_to admin_clubs_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Error Detected in the header of the Spreadsheet. Please read the instructions."
      render :index
    end
  end
end
```

Did I initialize the attributes wrongly? Or could I be parsing the CSV/Excel files wrongly?

Comment: On which line you are getting error ? what is the value of `params[:member_imports]` ?

Comment: this line:     attributes.each { |student_reg, value| send("#{student_reg}=", value) }

Comment: params[:member_imports] has an object value. member will have student_reg, name, position (in clubs). i am new to rails so i hope i answered your question